# Prism event aggregator Persistent Events

Tags: c#, wcf, events, prism, msmq

I have implemented Prism event Aggregators on my server where a service publishes an event and another one listens to it.
My subscription code:

```
 my_aggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Subscribe(Handler,true);
```

whereas I publish my event as:

```
my_aggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Publish(Payload);
```

> > The thing is that if the subscriber is alive then, everything works fine. But, lets say an event is published and the subscriber (is a service) somehow shuts down. Is there a way by which when the subscriber comes alive again it can respond to the event that was fired.

I have looked at netmsmq binding and how it provides a queue between services so even if the server shuts down loss of data can be avoided.

Will I have to hook it up with my current mechanism?? 
Or is there any other way this can be achieved??
 And are there any standard mechanisms of handling this?

**Edit:** It would be very much helpful if you can provide a link/code snippet that describes a path that can be taken to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a "store and forward" mechanism. Some years ago, I used the method described in [this article](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2008/11/adding-store-and-forward-support-to-the-prism-eventaggregator/) by [Ade Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125523/ade-miller) to accomplish the same thing. However, I have not done much with Prism for a few years and this article is circa 2008, so while the *method* described would probably still be applicable, the actual implementation might not be the same for newer versions of Prism...

Comment: http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2008/11/adding-store-and-forward-support-to-the-prism-eventaggregator/

Comment: @SyedOsamaMaruf - I fixed the link! Looks like you tracked it down anyway :)

Comment: Yup :) I will keep the thread open a day or two and if no better answer comes will accept yours as it has pointed me in a good direction

Answer (score 1):

PRISM Event Aggregator only guarantees the subscribers are notified (synchronously or asynchronously) when the publisher raises the event. It won't guarantee that the subscribers handle the "event" properly. In your case, the subscriber's `Handler` is invoked. That's all Event Aggregator can/should do. To make sure that your `Handler` works well (depends on the service is alive) and does not miss any `Payload`, you absolutely need something like `queue` mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question on codeplex forum and got the [answer](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/639156) from Bryan Noyes. It is:

> > I'm afraid you are cleanly outside what Prism pub-sub events were designed for. They were designed for loosely coupled components that are all in memory at the same time on the client side but you don't want to introduce coupling between those client components for them to communicate. For the kind of scenario you are talking about server side queues of some sort are the right answer, whether they are MSMQ-based, RabbitMQ, or Service Bus queues for Service Bus for Windows Server (or many other options along those lines depending on whether you want the queue to be on premise or in the cloud).

So in short prism pubsubevents aren't a good idea when it comes to server side events.